# multiple bone rotation mystery

Tags: xna, rotation, quaternions, 3d-modelling

I am working with quaternions and the XNA skinned model example(for weeks now......). I am received two sets of quaternions from some open source sensor boards that you can buy these days on the net. I was able to write some code so that I receive these quaternions and I am able to rotate limbs with them. Now my problem is the following. I am using the upper right arm and lower right arm in my example and I am able to rotate them separately. My initial position is the one depicted below, which perfect.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSjcb.png "initial position"

Now when I want to rotate my right arm forward I should have my final position as shown below on the right in this figure. But somehow the result is the one position of the left but my real "physical" arm is pointing forward.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOwvY.png "ideal final position(right), real wrong position(left)"

Some how the lower arm does not compensate for the rotation of the upperarm. I am sure I am missing one small step. Here below I have put the crucial part of the code I am using

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        HandleInput();

        UpdateCamera(gameTime);

        // Read gamepad inputs.
        float initposition = currentGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Right.X;
        float armRotation = Math.Max(currentGamePadState.ThumbSticks.Right.Y, 0);

        // these quaternions are received from bluetooth
        Upper.Z = Fq1;
        Upper.Y = -Fq2;
        Upper.X = -Fq3; // set 1 quaternions
        Upper.W = Fq4;
        //***************************

        forearm.Z = Uq1;
        forearm.Y = -Uq2;
        forearm.X = -Uq3;
        forearm.W = Uq4; // set 2 quaternions





        // set initial position
        if (initialpos == true)
        {
            initposition = 0.9f;
            R_forTransform = Matrix.CreateRotationY(initposition);

            R_forarminderinit = skinningData.BoneIndices["R_UpperArm"];
            L_forTransform = Matrix.CreateRotationY(-initposition);
            L_forTransform = Matrix.CreateRotationX(-initposition);
            L_forTransform = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(-initposition);
            L_forarminderinit = skinningData.BoneIndices["L_UpperArm"];

         }


        // Create rotation matrices for the upper and lower arm bones.

        Matrix upperarmTransform = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(Upper);
        Matrix forearmTransform = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(forearm);



        animationPlayer.GetBoneTransforms().CopyTo(boneTransforms, 0);
        if (initialpos == true)
        {
            boneTransforms[R_forarminderinit] = R_forTransform * boneTransforms[R_forarminderinit];
            boneTransforms[L_forarminderinit] = L_forTransform * boneTransforms[L_forarminderinit];
        }

        int forearmindex = skinningData.BoneIndices["R_Forearm"];
        int upperarmindex = skinningData.BoneIndices["R_UpperArm"];
        boneTransforms[upperarmindex] = upperarmTransform * boneTransforms[upperarmindex];
        boneTransforms[forearmindex] = (forearmTransform) * boneTransforms[forearmindex];
        animationPlayer.UpdateWorldTransforms(Matrix.Identity, boneTransforms);
        animationPlayer.UpdateSkinTransforms();
        UpdateBoundingSpheres();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

I would like to ask you if you could help me solve this mystery. I hope I have been as clear as possible in describing my problem. Furthermore I would like to thank you in advance for you effort.

Yours

Dave

Comment: are you sure are rotating the right bone? it seems that you want rotate from the shoulder and you are rotating from the elbow

Comment: maybe you're rotating them both at the same time somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have some mixed-up reference frames.  Here's what I think I'm seeing:

Your external sensors report their orientation relative to the world.  Your rendering code, on the other hand, deals with the lower arm in the upper arm's reference frame.

If we assume that the initial orientations are **q_u = [0,0,0,1]** and **q_l=[0,0,0,1]**, when you rotate your arm to point forward, the new orientations are both **[0,.707,0,.707]**, or something like that because both arm segments have experienced a rotation of **π/2** *relative to the world*.

When you render the arm, you rotate the *entire* arm (not just the upper arm) by **q_u**.  This makes sense, since you want to make sure that the elbow stays connected.  But then you rotate the lower arm by **q_l** and it has rotated twice as far as it should because it holds the shoulder's rotation.  If you were to hold your arm straight, but turn your body around, you would see the same thing happen: the upper-arm would rotate by the amount of body rotation and the lower-arm would rotate by that much again.

Perhaps the easiest way to deal with this is to remove **q_u** from **q_l**.  If **q_k** is the rotation of the lower arm *relative* to the upper arm, then **q_k** = **q_u'** * **q_l** where **q_u'** is the inverse quaternion (just negate the `w` component).